# Webex not using DNSSEC

Tags: cisco, dnssec, webex

our government issued a statement that all video/voice online enabling software needs to use DNSSEC for all address translations and all used DNS servers need to support DNSSEC.

I tried few DNSSEC checkers and analyzers (https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/www.webex.com) for "my_organization.webex.com" or even "webex.com" and to me it seems like this domain doesn't use/support DNSSEC.

I can't find any relevant information on Cisco/Webex website.

I for one can't believe Cisco Webex wouldn't use DNSSEC so my question is: Am I missing something? Or is there a reason to not use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that you are missing anything in this regard.
At least the `webex.com` zone is not signed as of this time (no `DS` exists for `webex.com`).
I do not know if any other domain names (which could potentially be part of signed zones) are relevant to their actual video conferencing solution. `cisco.com` is also not signed, for what it's worth.

As for why, we can really only speculate. Maybe they are dependent on legacy infrastructure? Maybe it's just not seen as a priority? Maybe a bit of both? Maybe something else altogether?

You should really reach out to the service provider (Cisco in this case) if you want answers, though. If nothing else, it may be valuable input for them that actual customers care about the issue.